# Using tmux for presentations

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, tmux

I know about sharing a `tmux` with a local socket, but what I want to do is slightly different: I would like to run it in a "presentation" mode, where the person who starts it has normal read-write access, and anyone who connects to the socket mode `777` can only watch. I have tried taking the write bit off the perms, but then `tmux` can't attach at all. Is there a configuration option that will allow this? Or an alternate tool that can support this use case? GUI screen sharing tools are out of scope, it has to be CLI.

Comment: How are folks connecting? If they can only connect via something that runs `attach-session -r` then the session should be read-only.

Comment: With `-S /path/to/socket` - but what I need is a way to enforce it from the POV of the first user, since otherwise any other user could become them.

Answer (score 2):

`tmux` **`attach`** has an option **`-r`** which does what is needed.

In the read/write session, start that normally.

For the read-only session do this

```
tmux attach -r
```

If you want to enforce providing only read-only access, you could ensure this by providing a "readonly" account on the machine whose shell automatically attaches to tmux, and limiting regular accounts on the machine to users who should have read/write access.

Comment: But how to enforce that only sessions with `-r` set are allowed to attach?

Answer (score 2):

[tmate](https://tmate.io/) Does this (its a tmux fork)

When run, you get four ephemeral public (!) addresses: SSH/HTTP, read / write.

If privacy is a concern, you can (a) only share read access, but anyone with the address can still watch, or (b) share control using ssh keys `tmate -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (disables web access)